# Centering an element with another element next to it

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design, css-position

What I'm trying to do is to have a text element centered, and then have an image just next to it.
[image: Position absolute centered]

Above is what I want to achieve, however it is done with `position: absolute;` and some really weird positioning values, that of course is not responsive and looks really weird.
My problem is I can only get the parent element centered, not the text only. The image must also be aligned just next to the text.

I've been searching for hours and can't seem to find a solution, but I'm sure it's such a simple fix. Thank you!

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/sigurdmazanti/pen/gOxMBem

**Code examples:**

```css
* {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.rabbit_absolute {
  position: absolute;
  right: 540px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>This text is centered</p>

<!-- position absolute -->
<header>
  <h2>This text is centered</h2><img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/cute-rabbit-png-12.png" class="rabbit_absolute">
</header>

<!-- regular flexbox -->
<header>
  <h2>This text is not centered</h2><img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/cute-rabbit-png-12.png" class="rabbit_flexbox">
</header>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it a bit simpler:

Center the `h2` text by making it an `inline-block` inside a regular div (no flex) that has `text-align: center`.

Then put the image *into*  the `h2`, apply `position: relative` to the `h2` (= anchor for absolutely positioned children)  and `position: absolute` to the image, which positions it in relation to the h2. Now you just have to choose negative `top` and `right` values (to move it *outside*  the parent) that relate to the image size  - see below.

```css
* {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
header {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

img.rabbit {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>This text is centered<img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/cute-rabbit-png-12.png" class="rabbit"></h2>
</header>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you, this solution is much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple trick. First you should put the `img` inside the `h2`
and set `position:absolute` on the image

**Html:**

```html
    <header>
      <h2>This text is centered<img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/cute-rabbit-png-12.png" class="rabbit">
    </h2></header>
```

**css:**

```css
    header{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .rabbit{
      position: absolute;
    }
```

This way you can center the *text* in `h2` using flexbox and the `img` will always stick to the side of the text

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple like this:

```css
    * {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: normal;
    }

    .cntr {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }


    img {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
      <div class="cntr">
        <h2>This text is centered</h2>
        <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/cute-rabbit-png-12.png" class="rabbit_absolute">
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Your code does the same thing my code does, it only centers the parent element. I think the small image size in my codepen is deceiving so that it looks centered. Updating it right now though

Answer (score 0):

You might play with margins in flexbox:

```css
* {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin:0 50px;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin:0 0 0 -50px;
}
```

```html
<p>This text is centered</p>

<header>
  <h2>This text is centered</h2><img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/cute-rabbit-png-12.png" class="rabbit_flexbox">
</header>
```